# How apply xsl transform in C# program without safe file?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I neen apply simple xsl transform and continue work whith result data, but I wan't to save file. This is my code:

```
XslTransform xsl = new XslTransform();
        var writer = new MemoryStream();
        var xslDoc = new XPathDocument("107901.xslt");
        xsl.Load(@"C:\Users\mak\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpellCheck\SpellCheck\GetAllValues.xslt");
        xsl.Transform(xslDoc, null, writer);
        writer.Position = 1;
        var str = new StreamReader(writer);
        var normalize = str.ReadToEnd().Trim('�');
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Save(normalize);
```

1) Why in variable str appears 2 symbol 65533?
2) Why variable normalize not save how xml file? Goes error 'not able to add it to the content characters than whitespace'

Maybe I doing all wrong and can easier.
Sorry for bad english and sanks for answer :-)

Comment: What kind of result to work with do you need, a string with the XML, an instance of `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, or what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand question no.1 so I'll skip to question 2. If you care to read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is clearly mentioned that the string argument of `Save()` should contains *"The location of the file where you want to save the document"*. As for populating the `XmlDocument` instance from XML string, you can use [`LoadXml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
.....
.....
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(normalize);
xmlDocument.Save("D:\path\to\your\output.xml");
```

Comment: About question 1. var normalize = str.ReadToEnd().Trim('�'); - I need use Trim, because in the begining substituted 2 symbol 65533. In xml and xslt file not present this symbol. Answer on question 2 ruight, thanks.